# Replace multiple occurrences of same symbol using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
$string = "hello---world";
```

How would I go about replacing the --- with a single hyphen?
The string could easily look like this instead:

```
$string = "hello--world----what-up";
```

The desired result should be:

```
$string = "hello-world-what-up";
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/-{2,}/','-',$string);
```

Comment: Is the braces performance significantly better then just '-+'?

Comment: Thanks Mark! :-D

Is it just as easy to have it remove a hyphen, if the string starts with one?

For instance having "--hello---world" turning out to be "hello-world"?

Comment: @KasperFP: That would be `preg_replace('/^-+/','',$string)`

Comment: For completeness, remove them at the end as well.
`preg_replace('/^-+|-+$/','',$string)`

Answer (score 2):

To remove them from the beginning and the end:

```
$string = trim($string, '-');
```

Comment: It isn't really helpful to post a partial answer 3 years after the question is asked

Comment: Many come through Google **daily**. This info is read every day for these three years and it will last. Unfortunatenly, couldn't add this as comment.

Answer (score 0):

try `$string = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('/--+/', '-', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I'm using - works like a charm :)

```
public static function setString($phrase, $length = null) {
    $result = strtolower($phrase);
    $result = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z-]/", "-", $result));
    $result = preg_replace("/--+/", "-", $result);
    $result = !empty($length) ? substr($result, 0, $length) : $result;
    // remove hyphen from the beginning (if exists)
    $first_char = substr($result, 0, 1);
    $result = $first_char == "-" ? substr($result, 1) : $result;
    // remove hyphen from the end (if exists)
    $last_char = substr($result, -1);
    $result = $last_char == "-" ? substr($result, 0, -1) : $result;     
    return $result;
}
```